# Counting sefirah in Welsh?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, language

The Welsh word for "week" is *wythnos*, which means eight nights.  This is because they count seven days, plus the six nights between them, and the one before and the one after.

Can someone who speaks Welsh count sefirah in Welsh after the first six days?  If you say "today is 7 days which is one wythnos" (according to google translate, "Heddiw yw saith diwrnod, sy'n un wythnos, o'r Omer", don't ask me how to pronounce that), you're not being accurate, since the eighth night is no longer part of the seventh day.

Comment: How many days in 2 welsh weeks? Won't there be overlap?

Comment: @ClintEastwood I checked on google translate, they say "dau wythnos" for two weeks.  I agree it sounds weird (at least for people like me who don't speak Welsh).  But if you want to be fancy and say it in one word like fortnight, they say pythefnos, which means 15 nights.  No idea how common one is vs. the other.

Comment: I just saw a modern Welsh calendar, and its the same as ours. So it seems that although the word Wythnos has an old intrinsic meaning, since the people there use it to refer to a standard modern 7 day week as we do, it means the same thing (since there is no other word for a 7 day week). I guess the question is what would a Jew do if he lived in Wales in Celtic times? I guess he will kick himself for not knowing Hebrew :)

Comment: There's no Chabad in Wales to email?

Comment: @DoubleAA AFAIK there's no Welsh Siddur Tehilas Hashem either.

Answer (score 3):

It seems from [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=f899xH_quaMC&pg=PA330&lpg=PA330&dq=wythnos%20welsh%20week%20eight%20nights&source=bl&ots=p0_zgeztZH&sig=9kURTNtUkJelrTeHkvGGpDlPXAQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHysiFk4zUAhUL7YMKHUJ2CmsQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=wythnos%20welsh%20week%20eight%20nights&f=false) that while the Welsh word literally meant "eight nights" and referred to an eight *day* week, it now just refers to a Judean seven-day week, and that's how it would be understood by the contemporary Welsh.   This should mean that it would be fine to count in Welsh.  Back when the meaning was actually an eight-day week, it should have been no better than using "fortnight" in English.  This is likely the case as well were the ancient Welsh to have had a a name for the 7.5-day unit you describe, since it is not the same as 7 days.